# Display Div, Set Timeout, Hide Div

Tags: javascript, css, function, position, display

When a div is clicked on, an image should appear, the disappear again after 3 seconds. The first line of the function gets it to appear, but if I add a timeout, nothing happens when the image is clicked. How do I fix this?

(also, if anyone could include how I can get the heart to appear in the centre on the #stickycat div please do!)

```js
function heart() {
    document.getElementById("heart").style.display = "block"
    setTimeout(fn(){ document.getElementById("heart").style.display = "none"}, 3000)
}
```

```css
#stickycat {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    right: 10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border: solid 4px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1);
    background-color:white;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1), -1px 1px 10px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1), -1px -1px 10px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1), 1px -1px 10px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1);
}
#stickycat img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    z-index:2;
    border-radius:50%;
}
#heart {
    animation: pulse 2s linear infinite;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:none;
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    50% { transform: scale(1.3); }
    100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<div id="stickycat" onclick="heart()">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9d/b1/3f/9db13f4f06bfa1600e970fd32f1851db.gif">
<img id="heart" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/1200px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png">
</div>
```

Comment: You should check your browser console for errors. `fn()` is not how one declares a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `fn()` is not a way to declare a function. You can declare an anonymous function by using `function()` keyword.

The `position` property of the heart is set to `absolute`. So the centering part can be managed by using the `top` and `left` css properties.

Below is the working example.

```js
function heart() {
    document.getElementById("heart").style.display = "block"
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("heart").style.display = "none"}, 3000);
}
```

```css
  #stickycat {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    right: 10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border: solid 4px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1);
    background-color:white;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1), -1px 1px 10px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1), -1px -1px 10px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1), 1px -1px 10px rgba(54, 215, 183, 1);
  }
  #stickycat img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    z-index:2;
    border-radius:50%;
  }
  #heart {
    animation: pulse 2s linear infinite;
    position:absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:none;
  }
  @keyframes pulse {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    50% { transform: scale(1.3); }
    100% { transform: scale(1); }
  }
```

```html
<div id="stickycat" onclick="heart()">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9d/b1/3f/9db13f4f06bfa1600e970fd32f1851db.gif">
  <img id="heart" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/1200px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png">
</div>
```